# Which is the best language for building a website?

Tags: json, web

I would like to make a website. I just wanted to get recommendations on which language I should use? Or if I need to use multiple languages, which ones should I use? I don't have any experience in website programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, first of all you can learn HTML and CSS, those are the basic for building a website.

Then, when you will be confortable with HTML and CSS, you can add a layer of difficulty and add some Javascript in it.

And then, when you will be ready, you can learn a back end language, but by the time you reach this, you will have your preferences about which one to learn.